# Getting the names of all classes / ids contained within a css file?

Tags: javascript, css

Is there a way, or a tool, which can be used to get a list of the names of all the classes / ids contained within a css file?

I need to build an xml mapping of all css classes / ids, and doing it manually is very tedious for css files that contain thousands of styles.

Comment: The title reads "css file", the first paragraph reads "javascript file" and the second one reads "css files". Which is it?

Comment: @PhistucK Sorry, that was a typo. I've fixed it. Its 'css files'

Comment: I did something similar by writing some code.

Comment: This looks like a parser, it might help you get where you want. http://codetheory.in/parsing-css-in-javascript/

Answer (score 13):

1. Include your css file into any html file.
2. In console execute the following code:

   Array.prototype.forEach.call(document.styleSheets[0].cssRules,function(a){console.log(a.selectorText)})
3. In the console will be the listing of all css tags used in your stylesheet.

Comment: This does not give classes but selectors.

Answer (score 2):

You can iterate over document.styleSheets to get each style sheet, then iterate over the rules to find everything that matches a class or ID selector. The following is a simplistic approach that provides a general approach, the regular expressions to get the classes and IDs from the rules needs more work.

```
function getClassesAndIds() {
  var sheet, sheets = document.styleSheets;
  var rule, rules;
  var classes = [];
  var ids = [];
  var temp;

  for (var i=0, iLen=sheets.length; i<iLen; i++) {
    sheet = sheets[i];
    rules = sheet.rules;

    for (var j=0, jLen=rules.length; j<jLen; j++) {
      rule = rules[j];

      // Get the classes
      temp = rule.cssText.match(/\.\w+/g);

      if (temp) {
        classes.push.apply(classes, temp);
      }

      // Get the IDs
      temp = rule.cssText.match(/\#\w+/g);

      if (temp) {
        ids.push.apply(ids, temp);
      }
    }
   }
  // Return an array of the class and ID arrays
  return [classes,ids];

  // or as an object
  // return {classes:classes, ids:ids};
}

window.onload = function() {
  console.log(getClassesAndIds());
};
```

From memory there were some quirks in older IE around sheets and rules but right now it evades me…

Comment: DOMException: CSSStyleSheet.rules getter: Not allowed to access cross-origin stylesheet ... when run in console.

Answer (score 1):

See my working example here :)

https://codepen.io/pixelfast/pen/rNrovmj

```
<script>
function getEm() {
  url = document.getElementById("url").value;

  fetch(url)
    .then((response) => response.text())
    .then((data) => {
      var cssText = data;

      var classRegex = /\.([\w-]+)/g;
      var idRegex = /#([\w-]+)/g;

      var classes = [];
      var ids = [];

      var match;
      while ((match = classRegex.exec(cssText)) !== null) {
        classes.push(match[1]);
      }

      while ((match = idRegex.exec(cssText)) !== null) {
        ids.push(match[1]);
      }

      console.log("Classes: " + classes);
      console.log("IDs: " + ids);

      document.getElementById("classes").innerHTML = classes + "<hr>";
      document.getElementById("ids").innerHTML = ids;
    });
}
</script>


<!-- HTML -->

<input style="width:400px" type="text" id="url" value="https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.3/assets/css/docs.css">
<button onclick="getEm()">Get Em</button>
<hr>
<div id="classes"></div>
<div id="ids"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case, i need all class names *(there are selectors which is start with ".icon-" )* in icons.css for listing all defined font icons.

```
const {cssRules} = Object.values(document.styleSheets)
      .find(sheet =>
        Object.values(sheet.cssRules).find(rule =>
          (rule.selectorText || '').match(/^.icon/)
        )
      ) || {cssRules: {}}

console.log(Object.values(cssRules).map(i => i.selectorText))
```